# How to pass array of string in swagger form data field

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I want to pass an array inside form data like below:

[image]

but I am getting the whole array as a string in NodeJS console like this:

```
{
  targetUniversity: "['613e3ecfefa725074cb17968', '613e3ecfefa725074cb17969']",
  targetBusinessType: "['freelancer','sw dev']",
}
```

The swagger file looks something like this,

```
"/announce": {
      "post": {
        "tags": ["Announcement"],
        "description": "Make an announcement",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "targetUniversity",
            "in": "formData",
            "type": "array",
            "description": "University ID in array []- from DD"
          },
          {
            "name": "targetBusinessType",
            "in": "formData",
            "type": "array",
            "description": "Business type (string - name) in array []"
          }
        ],
        "produces": ["application/json"],
        "responses": {
          "201": {
            "description": "announced successfully"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I just want the array itself, not the array in string format.

Comment: Just to clarify - does the request body need to be sent as form data (i.e. `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`) or as JSON?

Comment: Should be form-data only

Answer (score 1):

Array parameters need the `items` keyword to define the type of array items. Also, the operation must specify what MIME type(s) it `consumes`:

```json
        "consumes": [
          "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "targetUniversity",
            "in": "formData",
            "type": "array",
            "items": {           // <------
              "type": "string"
            },
            "description": "University ID in array []- from DD"
          },
          {
            "name": "targetBusinessType",
            "in": "formData",
            "type": "array",
            "items": {           // <------
              "type": "string"
            },
            "description": "Business type (string - name) in array []"
          }
        ],
```

In Swagger UI, enter the array items one per line and without quotes:

[image: Array parameters in Swagger UI]

Answer (score -1):

You can specify arrays in OAS3 as follows;

```
"parameters": [
    {
      "name": "targetUniversity",
      "in": "formData", -->> according to comments this should be replaced by requestBody in OAS3
      "schema": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "type": "string"
        }
    ...
```

The result will be like;

[image]

Comment: OP uses OpenAPI 2.0. And OAS 3 does not have `in: formData` parameters, it uses `requestBody` instead.

Comment: The previous one is a working example, but I do not know if it is supported in OAS3 or the library provides backwards compatibility...

Comment: Please see https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/

Comment: Note that this doc doesn't mention `formData` parameters - that's because in OAS 3 they were replaced with `requestBody`. See here: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/, section "Form Data". Your example is not valid OAS 3 syntax. You can use https://editor.swagger.io to check the syntax.